# Merged document from 2 pdfs is rotated horizontally/sideways using iText v5 pdf

Tags: java, itext

i am merging 2 pdf documents into one using Java and iText v5, in that one is Scanned image copy of PDF so iText is unable to read the content
in a way it is since this is image, hence Merged document is rotated horizontally/sideways.

if i use the iText rotate functionality methods, the content is cutting off. Let me know if any one faced this kind of issues with iText.

Comment: This sounds like you don't use `PdfCopy` for merging as is recommended.